# Cancel slurm job range in zsh

Tags: zsh, slurm

I am able to cancel slurm jobs by typing something like the following:

```
$ scancel 66421802_[11-20]
```

On bash, this works fine. However, on zsh I get the following error:

```
$ scancel 66421802_[11-20]
zsh: no matches found: 66421802_[10-20]
```

How can I cancel a job range when using zsh?

Comment: `[…]` is a wildcard for file name matching. On bash this only works if there's no file matching the pattern, e.g. `66421802_1`.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' and if the `nullglob` or `failglob` options are not enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[]` are special to ZSH, though can be turned off by way of the `noglob` precommand modifier, so maybe the alias

```
alias scancel='noglob scancel'
```

will do the trick, and also for any other commands that take `[]` as inputs.

Comment: Note that `[...]` is special to most shells where it is a glob operator (the most notable exception being `fish`) but in some shells including `bash`, if a glob doesn't match any file, it is left as-is which can make you think it's fine to leave it unquoted (but obviously isn't).